# How can multiple IndexOf be faster than raw iteration?

Tags: c#, string, iteration, indexof

```
string s = "abcabcabcabcabc";

var foundIndexes = new List<int>();
```

The question came from the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765819/more-efficient-way-to-get-all-indexes-of-a-character-in-a-string). I was simply wondering

How can this:

```
for (int i = s.IndexOf('a'); i > -1; i = s.IndexOf('a', i + 1))  

      foundIndexes.Add(i);
```

Be better than this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)

      if (s[i] == 'a') foundIndexes.Add(i);
```

**EDIT :** Where all does the performance gain come from?

Comment: Well, how about profiling it using `Stopwatch`?

Comment: isn't that the whole point of the second parameter of `IndexOf` - to tell the comparison to skip the initial characters

Comment: Theoretically, the code from the second variant might do the range checking for each index, whereas the first variant can omit it. Practically, the C# compiler is able to detect that `i` in always "in range", and skip the checks.

Comment: The `IndexOf` function would only iterate over each element one time since each subsequent `IndexOf` call begins the search at the index after the last found element.

Comment: Well I misphrased earlier... What I meant to ask was where the performance gain was coming from?

Comment: @loxxy: did you try the code with full optimization?

Comment: You need to provide the code you used to benchmark this; odds are your benchmarking method was biased towards one result in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not observe that using `IndexOf` was any faster than direct looping. Honestly, I don't see how it could be because each character needs to be checked in both cases. My initial results were this:

```
Found by loop, 974 ms 
Found by IndexOf 1144 ms
```

**Edit**: After running several more times I've noticed that you must run release (ie with optimizations) to see my result above. Without optimizations, the for loop is indeed slower.

The benchmark code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string target = "abbbdbsdbsbbdbsabdbsabaababababafhdfhffadfd";

            // Jit methods
            TimeMethod(FoundIndexesLoop, target, 1);
            TimeMethod(FoundIndexesIndexOf, target, 1);            

            Console.WriteLine("Found by loop, {0} ms", TimeMethod(FoundIndexesLoop, target, 2000000));
            Console.WriteLine("Found by IndexOf {0} ms", TimeMethod(FoundIndexesIndexOf, target, 2000000));           
        }

        private static long TimeMethod(Func<string, List<int>> method, string input, int reps)
        {
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            List<int> result = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                result = method(input);
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            TextWriter.Null.Write(result);
            return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        private static List<int> FoundIndexesIndexOf(string s)
        {
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

            for (int i = s.IndexOf('a'); i > -1; i = s.IndexOf('a', i + 1))
            {
                 // for loop end when i=-1 ('a' not found)
                indexes.Add(i);
            }

            return indexes;
        }

        private static List<int> FoundIndexesLoop(string s)
        {
            var indexes = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == 'a')
                indexes.Add(i);
            }

            return indexes;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOf(char value, int startIndex)` is marked with the following attribute: `[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]`.

Also, the implementation of this method is most likely optimized in many other ways, probably using unsafe code, or using more "native" techniques, say, using the native `FindNLSString` Win32 function.