# Getting character position in c#

Tags: c#, string

I am using following code to get Position of `"E"`

```
string a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a.Substring(i, 1) == "E")
    {
        position = i +1;
        break;
    }
}
```

above code will return `position = 5`,

I am new to C# my question is is any fast way without loop to do this,

Comment: The strange thing is that the duplicate has a similar string, the same character and even the same OP. You haven't learned a lot since then, have you?

Comment: 1k rep but no search effort, same question posted 10 months ago, ... that's not the way dude...

Comment: @xmashallax: OP has asked that question himself. That's the funny thing. So he just had to search in his memory.

Comment: Oh right ... that's even more disappointing...

Comment: sorry Guys, Actually I was posting to this Question on other comunnity , but due to i have habit to visit stack-over flow the question is posted here.. i was trying to delete it but already answer in 2 minutes and now it can now be delete..

Comment: @ImranAliKhan, I don't get that, why would you ask a question of which you already knew the answer (from your previous question)?

Comment: @MrCoder it is my persnal web site to practice web things , and shair with friends i was planned to checked my friends IQ level so i was planned to post this question my web site.

Comment: IQ level would not be tested by this question.

Comment: *I am new to C# my question is is any fast way without loop to do this,* suggests otherwise?

Comment: @MrCoder What do you mean by this..  suggests otherwise

Comment: *I am new to C# my question is* would suggest that you *weren't* testing friends' IQ, but then saying *this Question on other comunnity*. *checked my friends IQ level* suggests you already know the answer yourself? Is it my bad logic, or are things not ***quite*** adding up here?

Comment: @ImranAliKhan, Well, at least you've only the one vote I suppose...

Comment: @MrCoder I was already told to all that it is my web site where i was posting.. so i can use xyz user name to post, because I am admin and i can make any user which friends can not be know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MSDN reference String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int position = mystring.IndexOf("E");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int position = a.IndexOf("E");
```

It returns the first index of the character (or sub-string) or -1 if it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

---

## Single/First Occurrence

---

By using `IndexOf` will return the index of the position.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // A.
    // The input string.
    const string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM";

    // B.
    // Test with IndexOf.
    if (int i = s.IndexOf("E") != -1)
    {
        Console.Write("string contains 'E' at position of "+i);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This will output

> "string contains 'E' at position of 4".

**For a quick/better understanding:**

1. You can learn more [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof)
2. or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)

The indexOf gets you the position of the character (-1 will be returned otherwise)

---

## Multiple Occurrences:

---

If the char value appears multiple times throughout your string, you could use:

```
 var foundIndexes = new List<int>();

 for (int i = 0; i < myStr.Length; i++)

     if (myStr[i] == 'a') foundIndexes.Add(i);
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12765874/3913686)