# Get text between specific character

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the text between ';' character. However if there are 3 matches like that, i want to get the text between ';' character where current cursor position.  I am using multine textbox.

Example;

```
select * from database;

----> **Lets say my cursor is here** 
select 
orders from
customer;


select * from employees;
```

So, i only want to get '**select orders from customer**' text.

Could you please share your thoughts on it?

Comment: I am using multine textbox.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you first have to find all indicies of `;`. To do this, iterate through all indicies ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765819/more-efficient-way-to-get-all-indexes-of-a-character-in-a-string)):

```
private List<int> AllIndicesOf(string strToSearch, string fullText)
{
    List<int> foundIndices = new List<int>();
    for (int i = fullText.IndexOf(strToSearch); i > -1; i = fullText.IndexOf(strToSearch, i + 1))
    {
        foundIndices.Add(i + 1);
    }
    return foundIndices;
}
```

Then you have to compare your position to those indices, since you only want the index (of `;`) that follows immediately after your cursor:

```
List<int> indicies = AllIndicesOf(";", txtBxText.Text);
try
{
    if (indicies.Count > 0)
    {           
        int cursorPos = txtBxText.SelectionStart;
        var indicesBefore = indicies.Where(x => x < cursorPos);
        int beginIndex = indicesBefore.Count() > 0 ? indicesBefore.Last() : 0;
        int endIndex = indicies.Where(x => x > beginIndex).First();
        txtBxSelected.Text = txtBxText.Text.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex);
    }
}
catch { }
```

The `try-catch` statement is used to prevent an `Exception` if your cursors position is after all other indices.

A sample project can be [downloaded here](http://blog.abouchleih.com/wp-content/uploads/SOQuestion44341840new.7z).

Comment: wow. this is sooo nice. However, if cursor is middle of the word, it takes from after the cursor to ';' character. What i want is, all text between ';' charachter.

Comment: All right, I edited my answer and uploaded a new sample project.

Comment: Have anyone said that you are best and beast ?

Comment: Haha, I don't think I'm the best (not even close), simply trying to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution perfectly works although you need to check it again and consider some possible exceptions. I did not consider them myself because I thought it was better to be handled by you. I also used `richTextBox` which is better than the multi line text box. **Enjoy the code bro**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ultimateResult = string.Empty;
            var cusrPosition = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            var currentStr = string.Empty;
            var strDic = new Dictionary<string,int>();                
            var textArr = richTextBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < textArr.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (textArr[i] != ';')
                    currentStr = currentStr + textArr[i];
                else
                {
                    strDic.Add(currentStr,i);
                    currentStr = string.Empty;

                }
            }
            ultimateResult = strDic.First(item => item.Value >= cusrPosition).Key;
            textBox1.Text = ultimateResult;

        }
```